# There's a way to see error messages in New/EndNew in genexus?

Tags: genexus

I'm trying to insert new records in a table, but something is wrong and the record isn't inserted in the table.

I'm actually using the `new/endnew` to setting the properties of my object.

I know that if i use Business Component i can take the error messages using `.GetMessages()` but how i can take the error messages using `new/endnew`? There's a way to get this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that using a Business Component to do those tasks enforces the execution of the business rules defined in it, checks the foreign keys and updates related redundant formulas, whereas using `new`/`endnew` is akin to raw database insert.

You can use the `error_handler` [command](https://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?8238,Error_Handler%20Command)/[rule](http://wiki.genexus.com/commwiki/servlet/wiki?6853,Error_Handler%20Rule,) to capture DB errors (and act upon them)

Here is an example using `error_handler` commands:

```
Error_handler('OnDBError')
// the code that generates a violation

Sub 'OnDBError'
    msg(format(!'DBError: Code:%1  -  %2', &gxDBErr, &gxDBTxt), status)
    msg(format(!'Op: %1  -  Table: %2', &gxOper, &gxErrTbl), status)
    &gxErrOpt = 3
EndSub
```

- &gxDBErr is Numeric(5)
- &gxDBTxt is Character(255)
- &gxOper is
  Charater(30)
- &gxErrTbl is Character(255)
- &gxErrOpt is Numeric(1)

---

If you want to crate a log file you can activate the logging features of GeneXus (see the `Logging` section in the properties tab of your generator of choice)

Comment: where i should put the Error_handler function? Inside new? After?

Comment: before the new/endew. For example at the beginning of your procedure.

Comment: if you just want to get a log file you should activate the logging features instead

Answer (score 0):

The record that you want to save, is it from a default datastore table or a table by dataview?

Maybe the dataview is poorly defined.

Other things to try:

- Verify that the primary key is well defined (Messages of the data to
  be saved)
- Use "when duplicate" to display messages, in case the record
  with that key exists.